# Passing regex string to .net core rest API through post method

Tags: javascript, regex, decode, encode

I have a regular expression that i use to validate email address in JavaScript. Below is the regular expression

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

How can i escape/encode it to send through rest API and later on decode to use it again as regular expression?

Comment: Just wondering, did you try to wrap it in *'single quotes'* and send it over the server?

Comment: Why are you posting requests to and fro instead of just creating the regex as a constant in your script?

Comment: Send it as a string, then, in JS, use the `new RegExp(pattern)` to build a pattern from string. Make sure you double escape backslashes in a *string literal*. Sth like ``var str = "^(([^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";`` and in JS, `var rx = new RegExp(str);`